# Limit variable in NonLinearModel Fit to a list

Tags: fitting

I'm attempting to constrain the values of some of the model fit variables to a list of defined numbers. Here are a sample dataset and model.

```
data = {{0.375, 0}, {0.376, 0.01}, {0.377, 0.02}, {0.381, 0.05}, 
        {0.386, 0.1}, {0.396, 0.2},{0.425, 0.5}, {0.470, 1}, {0.549, 2}, 
        {0.727, 5}, {0.944, 10}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[d2, {(a/b)*x^2 + (a/c)*x^3 + d}, {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

I want `a, b, and c` (not `d`) to be one of the following numbers:

```
{10.0, 10.2, 10.5, 10.7, 11.0, 11.3, 11.5, 11.8, 12.1, 12.4, 
12.7, 13.0, 13.3, 13.7, 14.0, 14.3, 14.7, 15.0, 15.4, 15.8, 16.2, 
16.5, 16.9, 17.4, 17.8, 18.2, 18.7, 19.1, 19.6, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 
21.5, 22.1, 22.6, 23.2, 23.7, 24.3, 24.9, 25.5, 26.1, 26.7, 27.4, 
28.0, 28.7, 29.4, 30.1, 30.9, 31.6, 32.4, 33.2, 34.0, 34.8, 35.7, 
36.5, 37.4, 38.3, 39.2, 40.2, 41.2, 42.2, 43.2, 44.2, 45.3, 46.4, 
47.5, 48.7, 49.9, 51.1, 52.3, 53.6, 54.9, 56.2, 57.6, 59.0, 60.4, 
61.9, 63.4, 64.9, 66.5, 68.1, 69.8, 71.5, 73.2, 75.0, 76.8, 78.7, 
80.6, 82.5, 84.5, 86.6, 88.7, 90.9, 93.1, 95.3, 97.6, 100, 102, 
105, 107, 110, 113, 115, 118, 121, 124, 127, 130, 133, 137, 140, 
143, 147, 150, 154, 158, 162, 165, 169, 174, 178, 182, 187, 191, 
196, 200, 205, 210, 215, 221, 226, 232, 237, 243, 249, 255, 261, 
267, 274, 280, 287, 294, 301, 309, 316, 324, 332, 340, 348, 357, 
365, 374, 383, 392, 402, 412, 422, 432, 442, 453, 464, 475, 487, 
499, 511, 523, 536, 549, 562, 576, 590, 604, 619, 634, 649, 665, 
681, 698, 715, 732, 750, 768, 787, 806, 825, 845, 866, 887, 909, 
931, 953, 976};
```

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that your model is overparametrized. You could rewrite it as $p\ x^2+q\ x^3+ r$ and impose some constraints on the values of p and q.

Comment: The purpose of (a/b) and (a/c) is that these are resistor ratios. They are used in a summing op-amp, so a is the same for both scale factors.

Comment: Just curious:  usually there is some random error in the response and the response will rarely be a set of "nice" numbers.  So I have to ask:  is the order of the data {predictor, response} or {response, predictor}?

Comment: {predictor, response}

Comment: @MarcoB is correct.  You really only have 3 parameters:  a/b, a/c, and d. So your model is overparametrized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated to include OP's updated abc list.**

I assume that you want the triplet of a, b, and c (all from that list) that has the best fit (in the sense of minimizing the sum of squares).

You won't need `NonlinearModelFit` to do that (although you certainly could use `NonlinearModelFit` or `LinearModelFit` to get the same answer in this case).

Once a, b, and c are set, there is just a single parameter to be estimated:  d.  The maximum likelihood estimate of d will be

```
data = {{0.375, 0}, {0.376, 0.01}, {0.377, 0.02}, {0.381, 0.05}, {0.386, 0.1}, 
  {0.396, 0.2}, {0.425, 0.5}, {0.470, 1}, {0.549, 2}, {0.727, 5}, {0.944, 10}};
d = Mean[data[[All, 2]] - ((a/b)*data[[All, 1]]^2 + (a/c)*data[[All, 1]]^3)]
(* 1/11 (18.88 - (2.99769 a)/b - (1.90592 a)/c) *)
```

and the sum of squares will be

```
ss = (data[[All, 2]] - (d + (a/b)*data[[All, 1]]^2 + (a/c)*data[[All, 1]]^3))^2 // Total // Expand
(* 97.8981 + (0.556633 a^2)/b^2 - (14.7613 a)/b + (0.587834 a^2)/c^2 - (
```

15.1159 a)/c + (1.13778 a^2)/(b c) *)

So now just loop through all of the possibilities and choose the set of a, b, and c values that minimize the sum of squares.

```
abc = {10.0, 10.2, 10.5, 10.7, 11.0, 11.3, 11.5, 11.8, 12.1, 12.4, 
   12.7, 13.0, 13.3, 13.7, 14.0, 14.3, 14.7, 15.0, 15.4, 15.8, 16.2, 
   16.5, 16.9, 17.4, 17.8, 18.2, 18.7, 19.1, 19.6, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 
   21.5, 22.1, 22.6, 23.2, 23.7, 24.3, 24.9, 25.5, 26.1, 26.7, 27.4, 
   28.0, 28.7, 29.4, 30.1, 30.9, 31.6, 32.4, 33.2, 34.0, 34.8, 35.7, 
   36.5, 37.4, 38.3, 39.2, 40.2, 41.2, 42.2, 43.2, 44.2, 45.3, 46.4, 
   47.5, 48.7, 49.9, 51.1, 52.3, 53.6, 54.9, 56.2, 57.6, 59.0, 60.4, 
   61.9, 63.4, 64.9, 66.5, 68.1, 69.8, 71.5, 73.2, 75.0, 76.8, 78.7, 
   80.6, 82.5, 84.5, 86.6, 88.7, 90.9, 93.1, 95.3, 97.6, 100, 102, 
   105, 107, 110, 113, 115, 118, 121, 124, 127, 130, 133, 137, 140, 
   143, 147, 150, 154, 158, 162, 165, 169, 174, 178, 182, 187, 191, 
   196, 200, 205, 210, 215, 221, 226, 232, 237, 243, 249, 255, 261, 
   267, 274, 280, 287, 294, 301, 309, 316, 324, 332, 340, 348, 357, 
   365, 374, 383, 392, 402, 412, 422, 432, 442, 453, 464, 475, 487, 
   499, 511, 523, 536, 549, 562, 576, 590, 604, 619, 634, 649, 665, 
   681, 698, 715, 732, 750, 768, 787, 806, 825, 845, 866, 887, 909, 
   931, 953, 976};

results = Sort[Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, d, a/b // N, a/c // N, ss},
  {a, abc}, {b, abc}, {c, abc}], 2], #1[[7]] <= #2[[7]] &];

TableForm[results[[1 ;; 10]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"\na", "\nb", "\nc", "\nd", "\na/b", "\na/c", "Sum of\nsquares"}}]
```

[image: Table of sums of squares with parameter values]

Note that the top sets of parameters have pretty much the same values for `a/b` and `a/c`.  That is because the model really only has 3 parameters rather than 4.  Fitting the basic model with 3 parameters with `NonlinearFit`:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, ab x^2 + ac x^3 + dd, {ab, ac, dd}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {ab -> 10.9112, ac -> 2.29764, dd -> -1.65524} *)
```

The results match well with the table of parameter values above.

In short, the parameters `a/b`, `a/c`, and `d` can be estimated.  However, one cannot estimate `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: So the abc values can be the list of numbers given or those times 10, and I ran your code with the extended list and the values actually plotted versus the fit isn't as good as I've done by guessing from nonlinearmodel fit values and picking from the abc list.

Comment: I think ss should be ss = (data[[All, 
        2]] - (d + (a/b)*data[[All, 1]]^2 + (a/c)*
         data[[All, 1]]^3))^2 // Total // Expand?

Comment: You're right.  I forgot to add in `d`.  I'll fix that.

Comment: The abc values multiplied by anything but zero will give you the same predictions.

Comment: I don't think so. The available dynamic range would be reduced so the fit options would be limited.

Comment: Mutiply `abc` by `h` (just `h`, don't assign a value to it) and run the above code.  You'll get the exact same sum of squares.

Comment: Of course, you saw that once I expanded the table to have the 10x vales the square sums went down that would invalidate what you said in your comment.

Comment: Not at all. For any fixed abc list it holds.

Comment: How do you explain: {
 {102, 9.31, 45.3, 0.000381999}
}? 9.31 is a multiple of 93.1 and 931, but the R^2 is lower. As I see it the list is often incomplete because not every possible ratio is represented by the limited set.

Comment: You added new numbers that were multiples of the original numbers.  My statement is about multiplying any set of numbers by 10 (or Pi or the square root of 2, etc.) and you will get the same set of sums of squares.  There is a difference in those two scenarios.  This is because you can only estimate the ratio of a and b, the ratio of a and c, and d.

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  I still think I'm not understanding what you really want (and that's likely related to me not knowing the subject matter).

Comment: Thank you for your help/answer. I've been able to use it to get the answers I need. It may be nearly as good to use nonlinear model fit, then search abc to find the closest ratios that match the NLM terms.